# JasperStudio Parameter with SQL String

Tags: sql, parameters, jasper-reports

I am trying to create a dynamic SQL Query in JasperStudio.

Select * from table where user = 1
 AND RISKS = 'R'

The conditions, should only be executed on the database, when a certain parameter is set to TRUE (or 1).
If this parameter is FALSE, the query should neglect the conditions.
I thought of the following:

I use the conditions as its own parameter, and just set it '1', when the parameter is FALSE so the two statements would be:

1) Select * from table where user = 1
 AND RISKS = 'R'

2) Select * from table where user = 1
 AND 1= 1

But somehow, this does not work. Is there a better way to do this? The TRUE-FALSE Parameter will be set since I am accessing two different databases, and the RISKS column does only exist on one table (can't add the column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the Query Chunks (when you put into query `$!P{PARAM_NAME}` instead of `$P{PARAM_NAME}`).
Please have a look at the example below:

1. Declare params:

a) UserId param, you will pass to the query:

```
<parameter name="UserID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

b) UseRiskParam - is your "certain parameter which can be true or false"

```
<parameter name="UseRiskParam" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
```

c) Risks parameter - it will be applied to RISKS column if UseRiskParam = true

```
<parameter name="Risks" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

d) Now I define the parameter which generates additional condition. This parameter should be hidden. It generates the additional condition based on value of `UseRiskParam`. when it's true, condition will look like "RISKS = 1" else it will be "1 = 1"

```
<parameter name="RisksCondition" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{UseRiskParam} ? "RISKS = " + ($P{Risks} == null ? "null" : $P{Risks}.toString()) : " 1 = 1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

2. Report Query

> ```
> <queryString>
>   <![CDATA[select * from table where user = $P{UserID} and $P!{RisksCondition}]]>
> </queryString>
> ```

Because `$P!{RisksCondition}` is passed with `!`, it is passed as piece of sql statement but not as a query parameter.

Hope this info was useful

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will try it out over the weekend and post my results.